# Linking to bootstrap tabs directly without scrolling to anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a bootstrap tabs such as this - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Everything works fine, but I want to link each tab so I can access it directly

If I link using the anchor (#mytab), the page scroll to that anchor (and the users misses everything about the tab)

Is there a way to create a direct link to a certain tab (via anchor or another method) without scrolling happening?

Comment: Did you added required js files to your document?

Comment: yes a added required js but not work